# Selection on specific files

Tags: android, image, path

Hi I have an Image adapter which has list of all the images from CLC folder. But I want only files which are starting from 12345 (like a filter). is there any way to accomplish this?

Code :

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/CLC/";

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
{
    myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You juste have to check if the file name is like you want before you add it in your `Adapter`.

Do something like this:

```
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
{ 
    if (file.getName().startsWith("12345"))
       myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This will only fill your adapter with files that have a name starting with 12345.

You can check the [startsWith](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) function in the Android doc.